# Min value in mutidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
$data['key'] = array(11,5,7);
$data['value'] = array(78,54,96);
```

I have sorted it based on value. So now I have -

$data['key'] = (5,11,7);
$data['value'] = (54,78,96);

How can i get the first set of key-value pair i.e. the one which has the min value.

I want the o/p as -

```
(5,54)
```

can someone pls explain how this can be done?

Comment: Since that's not valid PHP code, it's hard to guess what those values actually look like. Please clarify.

Comment: @Monansh Please comment on few answer. then only we can understand what you need exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data['key'] = array(11,5,7);
$data['value'] = array(78,54,96);
$min = min($data['value']);
$key = array_search($min,$data['value']);
$result = array($data['key'][$key],$min);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
foreach($data['key'] as $val)
{
   if(isset($min_val)
   {
      if($val<$min_val)
      {
         $min_val=$val;
      }
   }
   else
   {
         $min_val=$val;
   }


}
```

YOU can also use `min()` function.
example:

```
   $output = array();
   $output []= min(array(11,5,7)); //will output 5
   $output[]=  min(array(78,54,96)); //will output 54
   print_r($output); //out put will be (5,54)
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean, something like this? i really dont know what you are trying to achieve

```
<?php
  // minimum value from both key and value
  $temp = array_map( "min", $data );
  print_r( $temp );

  // or if you only want to find the key of minimum value
  $value  = min( $data['value'] );
  $key    = $data['key'][array_search( $value, $data['value'] )];
  $temp   = array( $key, $value );
  print_r( $temp );

  // or if you want the first key value pairs
  reset( $data );
  $temp   = array( current( $data['key'] ), current( $data['value'] ) );
  print_r( $temp );
?>
```

Comment: syntax error? where, i tested it before posting and its working

Comment: @Monansh maybe you have old php that don't support anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asort` and get only the first key and value.

```
 asort($data);

foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
    echo $key." ".$val; break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following algorithm will solve what you want to achieve in O(n) time,

```
<?php
$data['key']    = array( 11, 5, 7 );
$data['value']  = array( 78, 54, 96 );

$min_value=$data["value"][0]; //temporarily set first element as current minimum
$min_index=$data["key"][0];

foreach($data["value"] as $key => $val){
    if($val <= $min_value){
        //we have a new minimum value 
        $min_value = $val;
        $min_index = $data['key'][$key];
    }
}

echo "($min_index => $min_value)";

?>
```